# How to remove the last repeating letters of a word

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How to convert `heyyyy` to `hey` using python regex ? 
This is what i got so far

```
line="heyyy hoooow are you"
word_normalize=compile(r'(\w)\1+')
word_normalize.sub(r'\1\1',line)
```

which prints `hey how are you`

i want it to print : *hey **hoooow** are you*

i want only the end letters to be shortened not the other parts.

and what if i wanted something like this
`hey hoow are you`
i.e the end characters don't repeat and other characters repeat at max 2 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\b` to force the match to be at the end of words.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\w)\1+\b', r'\1', line)
'hey hoooow are you'
```

To get the inner letters to repeat at max two times, add another substitution using `\B`, which is the opposite of `\b`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\w)\1+\B', r'\1\1', re.sub(r'(\w)\1+\b', r'\1', line))
'hey hoow are you'
```

Comment: what if i wanted something like this
`hey hoow are you`
i.e the end characters don't repeat and other characters repeat at max 2 times.